# Simulating Particle motion on a surface

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, applications, python, simulation

I am working on a personal project to model the motion of a particle on a surface.

Using calculus, I parametrized a surface and then found the normal vector to that surface.

Using that normal vector, I created the normal force the particle will experience at each point on that surface. That is, the normal force will generally be a function of position because this surface can have curvature.

In the case of a surface is a plane, then the normal forces work out to be constants.

When I simulate this plane case, all is well and the particle behaves as expected.

However, I took it one step further and attempted to do a parabolic surface. (z=x^2+y^2)

I do the same steps and get my equations of motion. I should also mention, that the equations of motion are second order, however, to use a numerical ODE solver, I just make them into first-order equations by reducing the order, and effectively doubling my number of equations.

However this time the simulation goes crazy. The trajectory of the particle does not stay on the paraboloid, and I think the culprit is the numerical error propagating. I am using the most accurate, high-fidelity "solve_ivp" solvers in scipy but it won't get any better.

I am attributing this due to the nonlinearity of the dynamics on the paraboloid since the normal vector is a nonlinear function of the position.

This is the image of the equations of motion for the paraboloid. The bottom right of this image is just converting them to first-order equations.
[EOMs on the paraboloid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP8dm.jpg)

[Simulation on the Paraboloid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpm20.png)

[An equivalent simulation on a plane. This one works well, probably since it is very simple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Aq6i.png)

This is my **Python Code** for it:

```
   def ode(t,q):

dqdt= np.zeros(6)

g=9.8

dqdt[0]= q[1]

dqdt[1]= -2*g*q[0] / (4*q[0]**2 + 4*q[2]**2 +1)

dqdt[2]= q[3]

dqdt[3]= -2*g*q[2] / (4*q[0]**2 + 4*q[2]**2 +1)

dqdt[4]= q[5]

dqdt[5]= g * ( (1/(4*q[0]**2 + 4*q[2]**2 +1)) - 1)

return dqdt



t_eval = np.arange(0, 5.001, 0.001)

q0= [1,0,1,0,2,0]

sol = solve_ivp(ode, [0, 5], q0,method= "DOP853", t_eval=t_eval)

x=sol.y[0]

y=sol.y[2]

z=sol.y[4]
```

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your particle is constrained to the surface, there is no need to worry about the normal force: you formulate the equations of motion on the surface by `eliminating' one co-ordinate